# GEKKO gives invalid inequalities

Tags: python, gekko

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

alpha = [20, 20, 20]
beta = [-0.2, -0.2, -0.2]
h= 0 ; b= 0 ; c= 0
#planning horizon 
t = len(alpha)
D = m.Array(m.Var, t ,lb=-0, integer=False)
P = m.Array(m.Var, t ,lb=-0,  integer=False)
AX = m.Array(m.Var, 1 ,lb=-0, integer=False)

m.Maximize( sum(D[i]*P[i]for i in range (t))-AX)

m.Equation(h*(c-sum(D[i]for i in range (t)))<= AX)
m.Equation(b*(sum(D[i]for i in range (t))- c)<= AX)
m.Equation(D[i]==beta[i]*P[i]+alpha[i] for i in range (t))

m.solve(disp=True) # solve on public server
```

Here, we are trying to maximize the sum of D[i]*P[i] where D is also a function of P. Unlike my other GEKKO models, this code doesn't work and I couldn't fix it by looking at the previously asked questions. The code gives following error:

```
@error: Inequality Definition
 invalid inequalities: z > x < y
 <generatorobject<genexpr>at0x00000193f21646d0>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Please fix your indentation in your code. Indentation is important in `python`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the last equation. It is a list of equations:

```py
m.Equations([D[i]==beta[i]*P[i]+alpha[i] for i in range(t)])
```

Here is a complete version that solves successfully:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

alpha = [20, 20, 20]
beta = [-0.2, -0.2, -0.2]
h= 0 ; b= 0 ; c= 0
# planning horizon 
t = len(alpha)
D = m.Array(m.Var, t ,lb=-0, integer=False)
P = m.Array(m.Var, t ,lb=-0,  integer=False)
AX = m.Array(m.Var, 1 ,lb=-0, integer=False)

m.Maximize(sum(D[i]*P[i] for i in range(t))-AX[0])

m.Equation(h*(c-sum(D[i] for i in range(t)))<= AX[0])
m.Equation(b*(sum(D[i] for i in range(t))- c)<= AX[0])
m.Equations([D[i]==beta[i]*P[i]+alpha[i] for i in range(t)])

m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True) # solve on public server
```

```
 Number of state variables:              9
 Number of total equations: -            5
 Number of slack variables: -            2
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              2
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0 -2.21893E+02  2.00000E+01
    1 -1.39989E+03  0.00000E+00
    2 -1.50000E+03  1.11022E-16
    4 -1.50000E+03  0.00000E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.520000002346933E-002 sec
 Objective      :   -1500.00000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```